# How may the situation, when there is no inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, definition, inertia

I want to know clearly the real concept of inertia.I have seen lot of definitions regarding inertia.But I could not exactly find real meaning of inertia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is inertia of a body?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193248/)

Comment: I wanted to imagine the situation when there is no inertia.

Comment: The body of your question only asks about understanding what inertia is. If you have a different question in mind I would suggest asking a new question, as this question already has answers on it, and you do not want to invalidate these answers. In your new question, you should explicitly mention why the linked duplicate is not sufficient for you, that way new the question won't be closed as a duplicate as well.

Comment: I got the answer for only what is inertia.It is almost bookish definition.

Answer (score 1):

> what is actually inertia?

Inertia is a property of matter by which it continues in its existing state of rest or uniform motion in a straight line, unless that state is changed by an external force (Oxford physics definition). It is the basis of Newton's first law of motion.

The amount of inertia that an object possesses is proportional to its mass. So anything that has mass has inertia.

> what happens if such property is not possessed by matter..ie, if there
>   is no inertia?

For one thing, it would mean you could accelerate an object without the application of an external force, in violation of Newtons first law. To the best of my knowledge such a phenomenon has never been observed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100192/discussion-on-answer-by-bob-d-what-is-actually-inertia-how-may-the-situation-w).